Extrude and Beveling a 2d Image in Illustrator
I have an image that looks like this. Everything is grouped and the larger rectangle is at the very back at the list.

Now whenever I extrude it, it appears like this:

Why does the puzzle icons get beveled inside? Shan't they come out too? Here is my file. Hope that someone helps me out by correcting me and teaching me something I am missing correctly. Thanks.

Ungroup them. Then select all, then apply the a 3D Materials Extrude & Bevel.
After you have done this, it will mess with the arrangement of the jigsaw puzzle pieces, but you can just select them and move them.
Here's an example

